# Participle adjective confusion

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, participial-adjectives

I know you can use past participle as an adjective, let’s say, *the laptop is built well*. But let’s say, I bought a designer bag, now I regret it, does it make sense to say *the money is wasted on this bag*?

Comment: The money _was_ wasted, since the purchase happened in the past.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Let's say I lost my laptop, then someone found my laptop and returned it to me, can I say 'my laptop is recovered' or 'my laptop was recovered'?

Comment: I think you could, but it would be _much_ more idiomatic to say 'it has been recovered'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, 'my laptop is recovered', 'my laptop was recovered yesterday', 'it has been recovered' are all acceptable?

Comment: Yes, but the last two are the ordinary verb and not the participle being used as an adjective.